# Restore arp cache in linux

Tags: linux, mac-address, arp

I accidentally delete HWaddress using below command

```
arp -d 200.9.12.50
```

if i run the arp -n 200.9.12.50 shows **incomplete**.

```
Address                  HWtype  HWaddress           Flags Mask            Iface
200.9.12.50                       (incomplete)                              eth0
```

I know the exact HWaddress, tried to add manually using below command. I am not able to ping (Destination Host Unreachable), If i reboot the arp will be again set to **incomplete**. Please help me the restore the arp with HWaddress.

```
arp -s 200.9.12.50 00:0b:ab:7d:09:4a temp
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The linux kernel sets the completed arp flag only when the neighbor unreachability detection (nud) state is set permanent (not temporary) or "valid" ([arp.c#L1077-L1085](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/2f4c53349961c8ca480193e47da4d44fdb8335a8/net/ipv4/arp.c#L1077-L1085)).

```
#define NUD_VALID   (NUD_PERMANENT|NUD_NOARP|NUD_REACHABLE|NUD_PROBE|NUD_STALE|NUD_DELAY)
```

*[net/neighbour.h#L38](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/c60174717544aa8959683d7e19d568309c3a0c65/include/net/neighbour.h#L38)*

---

Looking at net-tools arp.c, this is set in [arp_set()](https://github.com/ecki/net-tools/blob/master/arp.c#L306-L312). (See [net-tools](http://net-tools.sourceforge.net/) for official source.) If the `temp` arg is supplied, the permanent flag is disabled which might explain "If i reboot the arp will be again set to incomplete."

---

Try removing the entry and resetting it without temp:

```
# arp -i eth0 -d 200.9.12.50
# arp -Ds 200.9.12.50 eth0
```

(I use iproute2 instead of net-tools; forgive me if any of this information is incorrect.)